# IONIC - ion-datetime time wheel doesn't dismiss when click on backdrop and neather the default buttons

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<sub><ng-template #INTERVALS>
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-col
                size="12"
                slot="start"
            >
                <ion-text class="ion-margin-start ion-text-size-20 ion-text-weight-500">{{ 'new_time_slot' | translate }}</ion-text>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <form [formGroup]="intervalForm">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ 'description' | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-input
                    formControlName="description"
                    slot="end"
                    class="ion-text-right"
                ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ 'price_list' | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-select formControlName="priceList">
                    <ion-select-option
                        *ngFor="let priceLevel of priceLevelList"
                        [value]="priceLevel?.name"
                    >
                        {{ priceLevel?.name }}
                    </ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ 'slot_color' | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-input></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item
                lines="none"
                class="ion-margin-top"
            >
                <ion-label class="ion-text-uppercase">{{ 'interval_time' | translate }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ 'from' | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-datetime-button datetime="fromtime"></ion-datetime-button>
                <ion-popover [keepContentsMounted]="true">
                    <ng-template>
                        <ion-datetime
                            id="fromtime"
                            #fromtime
                            hourCycle="h23"
                            presentation="time"
                            value="{{ intervalFrom }}"
                            (ionChange)="timeChange('from', fromtime.value)"
                        >
                            <ion-buttons slot="buttons">
                                <ion-button
                                    color="primary"
                                    (click)="DismissClick()"
                                >
                                    Done
                                </ion-button>
                            </ion-buttons>
                        </ion-datetime>
                    </ng-template>
                </ion-popover>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ 'to' | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-datetime-button datetime="totime"></ion-datetime-button>
                <ion-popover [keepContentsMounted]="true">
                    <ng-template>
                        <ion-datetime
                            id="totime"
                            #totime
                            hourCycle="h23"
                            presentation="time"
                            min="{{ intervalFrom }}"
                            value="{{ intervalTo }}"
                            (ionChange)="timeChange('to', totime.value)"
                            [showDefaultButtons]="true"
                        ></ion-datetime>
                    </ng-template>
                </ion-popover>
            </ion-item>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer class="ion-padding ion-no-border ion-text-right">
        <ion-button
            color="danger"
            (click)="modalCtrl.dismiss(data)"
        >
            {{ 'cancel' | translate }}
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button
            color="danger"
            (click)="onSubmit(intervalForm.value)"
        >
            {{ 'add' | translate }}
        </ion-button>
    </ion-footer>
</ng-template></sub>
```

I simply copy the ion-datetime-button example showed on Ionic doc and added some customization for my purposes.

When i click on ion-datetime-button it show the time wheel correctly and i am able to change the time, but when i try to close it nothing happened and the wheel keep showing. It stacked all the page and until i refresh the page it doesn t dismiss. ANY HELP PLS ?

Comment: please post a reproducible example. Where is the actual code? HTML is not sufficient.